# Application Insights: Some metrics not coming through, unsure how to respond to error messages

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm new to Application Insights.

The details in this ticket relate to a specific API, written in C# with .NET Framework (not Core), running in IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter virtual machine.

We have a lot of the Application Insights metrics for this API coming through as expected, including some custom telemetry we coded ourselves that has been extremely useful.

But a few key things such as the requests per second and the failed requests per second are not coming through.

I've done some digging, and I've found some trace information in the Application Insights logs for that specific API that look like they might be related, but I'm not sure what to do with them.

Here's one example:

> AI: Error collecting 3 of the configured performance counters. Please check the configuration.
>
> Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests/Sec, instance _LM_W3SVC_4_ROOT
>
> Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Request Execution Time, instance _LM_W3SVC_4_ROOT
>
> Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests In Application Queue, instance _LM_W3SVC_4_ROOT

Another example:

> AI: ApplicationInsights configuration file loading failed. Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StatusMonitor.SdkSourceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.StatusMonitor' was not found. Type loading was skipped. Monitoring will continue.

Here's the ApplicationInsights.config file for the website in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <!-- Extended list of bots:
            search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client-->
      <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StatusMonitor.SdkSourceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.StatusMonitor" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
      <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        <!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers. 
        This is only applicable if Profiler is installed via either StatusMonitor or Azure Extension.
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
        <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
        <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
        <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
      </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
      <!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:

      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
      </Counters>

      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Handlers>
        <!-- 
        Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

        NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
      </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
  <TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
      <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
  <!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  -->
  <InstrumentationKey>**removed**</InstrumentationKey>
  <ResourceID>**removed**</ResourceID>
  <StatusMonitor>2.3.0</StatusMonitor>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

The host machine is running Windows Server 202 R2 Datacenter as part of an Azure VM.

Because I'm new to this, I'm not really sure where to start. I've tried googling the error messages but I'm not coming up with much that seems useful to my current situation.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

What is the version of the SDKs you are using? And did you add application insights SDK to the application itself, or used Status Monitor to instrument the app at runtime?

The error about PerfCounters indicates that the SDK encountered error trying to collect the counters mentioned. Are you seeing other counters like Process CPU, Memory etc? If yes, then the issue is with Asp.Net related counters only. Can you use a tool like perfmon and validate that these counters do exist in the machine?

You can remove the following line from Ai.Config to get rid of the error about StatusMonitor initialier - I am not sure what does it do, but it cannot explain why you are missing some data.

`<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.StatusMonitor.SdkSourceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.StatusMonitor" />`

To really explain why you are not seeing 'Requests' related metric, need to see web.config of your application. You may be hitting this issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/569

Please share some more information - sdk version, web.config, how onboarded etc and I am try to help more.